# How to change timeout in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good morning everyone!

I've got a question, I am not sure which language I should really be using. I'm assuming javascript since the slideshow is javascript.

I need to create a slideshow where a user can change the time in between slides. There are about 100 slides and they want to be able to set the timing in between each individually.

I've put all the pics on the server and created a db with the links to them and the slideshow works just fine, except I can't seem to figure out a way to make the timeout have different values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Weather Show</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsiveslides.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function display_c(){
     var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
     mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
     var strcount
     var x = new Date()
     document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
     tt=display_c();
}
</script>


<?php
echo "<script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#slider1').responsiveSlides({
                        maxwidth: 1080,
                        speed: 1000,
                        timeout: 5000
                        });
                    });
              </script>";

echo "</head>
<body style='background-color: #000;' onload=display_ct();>
<div id='wrapper'>";  

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM weather WHERE status = '1'");
?>

<!-- Slideshow 1 -->
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
<?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<li><img src='"; echo $row['link']; echo "' alt='"; echo $row['link']; echo "'></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div><!-- end wrapper -->

<div style=" margin-top:-30px; ">
<span id='ct' style="font-weight:bold; font-size:36px; color:#FFF; margin-left:30px;"></span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I was going to use PHP variables for the time, that's why I'm just echo(ing) the javascript. That did not work too well for me. So if anyone knows how to do this and wants to let me know, it would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: You can add the timout in the image, like Data-Timeout Then read that value after each sliding animation, and check what the new value is of the active image. Clear the timeout and set a new one.

Comment: You cannot use the plugin's `timeout` setting, because it sets the interval with no reference. You will have to use the plugin's `slideTo(idx)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this at the javascript side if you put the `refresh` and `mytime` variable more global. 
Keep track of your `mytime`-variable (from `display_c()`). Add your edit box and whatever event you need to track that a new interval was specified.

As soon as that event is triggered you call `clearTimeout(mytime);` to stop the time, update the `refresh` variable with the new value and call `display_c()` again to start the process anew:

```
<?php
   $refresh = 1000; // Current value from database
   echo <<<JAVAVSCRIPT 
   <script>

   $(function () {
         $('#slider1').responsiveSlides({
            maxwidth: 1080,
            speed: $refresh,
            timeout: 5000
         });
    });

    $('#speed-input-id').change(function(e) {
        refresh = parseInt($(this).val());
        $.ajax('/updateTheDatbaseTimeoutValueUrl', {data: {refresh: refresh}});
        // I can't help you on reconfiguring the plugin, too little information
        updateTheResponsiveSlidesTimeout(refresh); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 });
```

Comment: OK, I'm a total noob when it comes to javascript. I had it sort of working with using a php variable that I was getting from my db. The only issue I was having with that is that it would only use the last entry for all the time intervals.

Comment: Assuming you are using jQuery here you can add an ajax call to update your backend for the initial value. I'll update the example.